# Microsoft Graph API - find message by internetmessageid

Tags: email, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I need to find conversationId for email exchange between two user - John and Harry.
In my scenario:

1. John sends message to Harry.
2. I have email metadata from email that John has sent, e.g. converstationId, internetMessageId, messageId (m$ graph user specific).
3. Now I would like to reply from Harry. Unfortunately the converstionId of Harry is different then John, so I can't use it. What I would like to do is to find email message object in Harry's inbox and use his conversationId.
4. With valid converstationId, I would be able to call replyAll on Harry behalf.

Can I make call like:
GET /me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq abcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<1430948481468.34600@THCIE7Dev2.onmicrosoft.com>'
```

BUT

One must URL encode the internetMessageId

Thus

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '%3C1430948481468.34600%40THCIE7Dev2.onmicrosoft.com%3E'
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can make a GET call in the form you suggest - have you tried it? The graph API supports [standard ODATA query parameters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters).

On the [graph API explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), the following call works for me:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<1430948481468.34600@THCIE7Dev2.onmicrosoft.com>'`

Comment: Worked for me, but had to remove the < >

Comment: I tried the same thing, but it didn't work for me. Is anyone else able to do this ?

Comment: @SwastiGupta if you're still stuck, maybe ask a new question and provide some details about what you're trying and what the error/behaviour is that you're seeing.