# Fetch Exchange online message details using InternetMessageId

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

When I get an event of `SendAs` (from other MS audit source) it contains very little info of the message itself, but has an `InternetMessageId` identifier.
I'm trying to fetch additional info using it but get only errors.

Firstly w/ the `MessageTraceDetail` [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/get-messagetracedetail?view=exchange-ps), I tried to fetch by either using the `InternetMessageId` as `MessageId` and as `MessageTraceId`, both return w/ same error:

`GET https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTraceDetail`
with query: `"$filter" -> "MessageId eq guid'<AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com>'"`

`{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Unrecognized 'Edm.Guid' literal 'guid'<AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com>'' at '13' in 'MessageId eq guid'<AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com>''."
        }
    }
}`

Secondly, w/ the [Microsoft Graph API of get message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_get)

I created an AD App and granted it both Application and Delegated permissions of all "mail" related.

The request was w/ user principal name and the message id:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myuser@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com/messages/%3AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com%3E`

which produces a generic 500 `Internal Server Error`.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other API to use that allow the get the message details using the `InternetMessageId` ?

Answer (score 0):

> > GET https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTraceDetail
> >     with query: "$filter" -> "MessageId eq guid''"

While the MessageId can contain a GUID it's not a Guid datatype so just query it as a String however you will need to escape the string to use it eg

System.Uri.EscapeDataString(("MessageId eq '" + InternetMessageId + "'")

> > https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myuser@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com/messages/%3AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com%3E

the id being referred to here is the Exchange Store identifier for the item which is different from the InternetMessageId you have to search for the Message using the InternetMessageId eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE@mycorp.onmicrosoft.com>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to the following request of Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<1430948481468.34600@THCIE7Dev2.onmicrosoft.com>'
```

For more, please see the link:
[Microsoft Graph API - find message by internetmessageid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556311/microsoft-graph-api-find-message-by-internetmessageid)